# How to change the delay variable Td for a tline component in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, delay

I want to change the transmission delay-time `Td` (see picture) of a **tline**-component in LTspice as a function of time during simulation. 
From my understanding, I cannot do that using the `.step` command, since that would generate individual simulations, each with a distinct value of the delay-variable `{Td}`.

[image]

Is the delay a variable that can be changed in time using a transient LTspice simulation?

Comment: maybe you can hack somethign up with .model ako?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tline` and `ltline` models have fixed delay, i.e. they cannot be a function of time. If you need such a delay, you can only use a behavioural source with the builtin function `V=delay(V(in), f(time))` (for `BV` source, for ex.), where `f(time)` is a function defined previously with a `.func` statement, or made up ad hoc (e.g. `V=delay(V(in), V(control))`).

You should know that, while you can use that, in both `.AC` and `.TRAN` analyses, in the latter it *may* suffer from minor (seemingly erratical) drifts, depending on the configuration of your schematic. One cause may be the numerical accuracy (dynamic range) which, unfortunately, affects the behavioural sources, but I can't point out exactly what/who/where, I'm afraid that's up to you to find out.

Alternatively, you can build your own LC delay line built with the behavioural inductors (`Flux=f(x)`) and capacitors (`Q=f(x)`), but I, personally, would recommend avoiding. Your choice.